# hair simulation too slow and cache inaccessible

Tags: particles, physics

I'm using Blender hair particles for simulating grass and there are two issues.

1) Hair simulation is too slow, even when I set the number to 5 just to check how the grass blades move around. (No there are no Force Fields currently).

2) "Cache" is missing when "Hair" mode is used. This is Blender 2.76b

[image]

This means I can neither clear the cache nor bake the animation so I can preview it in the 3d view before so I know everything is fine before running the day-long rendering of the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable [Hair Dynamics](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/hair_dynamics.html) in order Particle System set to *Hair* mode to have cache, because

> When set to hair mode, particle system creates only static particles, which may be used for hair, fur...

[wiki page](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/hair.html#hair).

This type of Particle System may be animated [using the cloth solver](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/hair.html#animating).

Baking particle system may be neccessary if something happens in the scene, i.e. animation is involved. If dynamic hair is disabled, it seems like hair won't change, so nothing to bake.

After you enable Hair Dynamics, Particle System will be accessible for baking results and previewing animation when it's played (and so on):

[image]

Comment: The info in the wiki isn't correct, the Hair particles are being animated the other way too.

Comment: @LeoErvin It can be animated if using Force Fields which have location data animated; afaik no other really useful way  There won't be possibility to play animation and see some changes if *only* hair particles and *fixed* force field are used.